Possible contradiction between happens-before relationship and out-of-order execution in a single thread
I'm reading Rust Atomics and Locks (O'Reilly Media, Inc.).
In Chapter 3. Memory Ordering, it first says

Processors and compilers perform all sorts of tricks to make your programs run as fast as possible. A processor might determine that two particular consecutive instructions in your program will not affect each other, and execute them out of order, if that is faster, for example. (snip) Similarly, a compiler might decide to reorder or rewrite parts of your program if it has reason to believe it might result in faster execution. But, again, only if that wouldn’t change the behavior of your program.
Let’s take a look at the following function as an example:
fn f(a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32) {
*a += 1;
*b += 1;
*a += 1;
}
Here, the compiler will most certainly understand that the order of these operations does not matter, since nothing happens between these three addition operations that depends on the value of *a or *b. (Assuming overflow checking is disabled.) Because of that, it might reorder the second and third operations, and then merge the first two into a single addition:
fn f(a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32) {
*a += 2;
*b += 1;
}
Later, while executing this function of the optimized compiled program, a processor might for a variety of reasons end up executing the second addition before the first addition, possibly because *b was available in a cache, while *a had to be fetched from the main memory.

Please note the example (i.e. f()) is single-threaded.
However, the chapter later says

The basic happens-before rule is that everything that happens within the same thread happens in order. If a thread is executing f(); g();, then f() happens-before g().

It sounds like the two explanations contradict with each other. Am I missing something?

I think the happens-before rule applies to observable behaviour. The observable results of f(); g(); must be as if f() was executed before g(), and compiler and processor are only allowed to reorder operations in a way that doesn't change the results in any observable way.

@SvenMarnach: Not even that.  Another thread is allowed to observe the results of g() before it observes the results of f().

@NateEldredge If we limit the discussion to a single-threaded environment, do you think Sven's comment above is correct? Actually, the OP explicitly includes the phrase "in a single thread" in its title to discuss only single-threaded environment.

@ynn: If the program only has one thread, then yes.  It's always been true that a thread observes its own operations as if in program order.  But in a single threaded program, happens-before is just another name for program order and it introduces nothing new.  The memory model doesn't have anything novel to say about what happens for single-threaded programs; the point of it is to define the behavior of multi-threaded programs.

This is a common point of confusion, but it's just terminology.
Happens-before is just the name of a certain abstract partial ordering defined as part of the formal memory model.  It is required to obey certain constraints (like being consistent with source code program order, as you mention), and the observable behavior of the program is constrained in certain ways by the ordering (for instance, if a store S to a variable happens-before a load L of that same variable, then L is guaranteed to return either the value stored by S or some later value, with respect to the modification order on that variable).
However, at least when first learning, you should not think of it as having any connection to the ordinary English meanings of the words "happens" and "before".  (For this reason, I like to write the term happens-before hyphenated and in italics, so that it looks distinctly different from the ordinary English phrase.)  In particular, given two operations A and B, knowing that A happens-before B does not imply any of the following:

It does not necessarily imply that operation A is performed at an earlier instant in time than operation B.  (Indeed, most memory models explicitly refuse to guarantee that there is any single consistent "clock" for the program's operations, somewhat like the situation with relativity in physics.)

Within a single thread, it does not necessarily imply that the machine instructions for A must appear in program order before, or be executed before, the instructions for B.

It does not necessarily imply that the effects of A will become visible to other threads before those of B.


So you really just have to understand the term as meaning what its formal definition says, no more and no less, and resist the temptation to read anything further into the words "happens before".

Within a single thread, it does not necessarily imply that the machine instructions for A must appear in program order before, or be executed before, the instructions for B. If that is NOT implied, what's the happens-before rule in a single thread? I think the reason I feel difficulty is I don't even know the name of the rule in the OP: The basic happens-before rule is that everything that happens within the same thread happens in order. If a thread is executing f(); g();, then f() happens-before g(). How should I google to self-learn more about the rule?

In other words, it is easy to (at least try to) learn Relaxed, Release, ... memory orderings in multi-threaded environments because they have their names. I can just google the names. However, I don't know the name of the happens-before rule in a single thread. The book introduces the rule without naming it.
